# React native push notification change the graphics

Tags: java, android, reactjs, react-native, push-notification

I'm using the following module: https: //github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/

I would like to create a graphic like the one you see in the image.

But I found nothing in the documentation.

Can anyone give me some advice if you can or should I use another module?
[image]

Comment: I dont think its possible to create a custom notification using react native using any of the libraries out there as of today, You would need to switch to android to handle that part.

Comment: Searching on the internet, I found this thing: setCustomBigContentView
I'm trying to figure out if I can and how I can use it.

Comment: That's exactly what you need to use but its available in android, your own code where you pass data from react native to native android and then freely generate whatever notification you want, its not that difficult just follow the react native documentation.